# How to package resource file with Java adapter in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 / 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

What is the best way to package a resource (file) into a Java adapter?  It is not clear from the documentation the best way to deploy this with the adapter archive so that it can be used by the adapter.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

MFPF 6.3 does not support Java adapters, so that's moot there. If you want to use Java code in your **JavaScript** adapter in 6.3, then you can do so as demonstrated here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/server-side-development/using-java-adapters/

MFPF 7.0 does support Java adapters; the adapter has a **lib** folder. You can use this folder to hold your libraries to use within the adapter logic:

-https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/server-side-development/java-adapter/
- also see section "adapter sandbox": http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_overview_of_ibm_java_adap.html?lang=en